# Php mysqli result is null or zero then echo 0

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to write a piece of PHP for if a mysqli query returns a value less than 1 or a null result to display as a 0 in a table.

My question is do you write this as part of the mysqli query or as an if statement based on the query result?

So far I have:

Mysqli query below (I have a DB connection and the below query which works)

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT SUM(Column_NameA) as total FROM table_name WHERE Column_NameB = '".$_SESSION["username"]."'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$sum = $row['total'];
```

In my HTML table I've inserted the below but can't workout how to display a 0 if the query doesn't find any data (i.e. null result):

```
<?php if ($sum === 0) {echo '0';} elseif ($sum > 0) {echo $sum;} ?>
```

Any ideas are welcome..

Comment: Obviously `$row['total']` is a string. Use `==` or cast `$row['total']` to int.

Comment: ternary - `echo (!empty($sum)) ? $sum : 0;`

Comment: `echo sprintf('%d', $sum)`. if $sum is a non-integer value, it'll just print as `0`.

Comment: @u_mulder: uh, how could it be a string? `sum()` returns an integer, or an sql null.

Comment: or `echo (int)$sum;` That should work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a shorthand `if statemen`t will do :)

```
echo $sum > 0 || $sum!==null ? $sum : "0";
```

Comment: No problem,  you can mark the answer if it work for you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could append a default value inside of the database on the total column (as 0) and simply output it or use the `empty()` function inside a ternary if expression.

`echo (!empty($sum)) ? $sum : 0;`